# Workaround for Chrome 53 printing table header twice on 2nd and later pages?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, html-table

Users of my website need to be able to print web pages consisting of content on the first printed page followed by a table on the second page.  A stripped down version is (jsFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/jaydeedub/n3qhvtvx/25/ ):

HTML:

```
<body>
  <button class="button" onclick="window.print()">Print Me</button>
  <div class="page1">
    This is the page 1 content. Blah, blah, blah.
  </div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Page 2 table header prints twice</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Page 2 table body</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>Page 2 table footer</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@media print {
  div.page1 {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 16px;
}

.table>thead>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button {
  width: 6em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

This prints as expected in Chrome 52 on Chrome OS, but in Chrome 53 on Windows 7 Home and Chrome 53 on Chrome OS, the table header prints twice on the second page: once by itself without the top margin, and once with the top margin, followed by the rest of the table.  It used to print normally in Windows in an earlier version of Chrome, but I do not know if that was Chrome 52 (definitely within the last few versions).  It also prints as expected in Firefox.

I found one workaround, which is to put an empty 'thead' element before the real 'thead' element, but this solution is very kludgy and makes me uncomfortable.

Is there a more robust workaround that would be likely not to have side-effects across browsers?

Comment: For reference here's the same [issue I posted on the Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/5r_7BoH7Ev4/6d8w17cgAgAJ).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My temporary solution:

```
thead {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

Comment: For my situation, this solution is the most practical way around the problem.  I have quite a few pages to fix, so I prefer to deal with it in my CSS rather than go into each one, change the 'thead's to 'tr's, and then have to change them back again when the issue is fixed in Chrome.

Comment: I have no idea how you found this workaround so quickly, but it works for me so thanks. I knew supporting printing would come back to bite me because of self-updating browsers...

Comment: was scratching my head for hours on what change in my code caused this issue! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Reared its "thead" iin chrome 56... This appears to have fixed the issue. What is strange is that the jsfiddle doesn't appear to show the issue anymore in 56, but my own site did. Either way, much appreciated.

Comment: Still seeing this problem in Chrome Version 64.0.3282.168 (Official Build) (64-bit). The @liewzy fix helped me. There is an [old bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=631222)  but found other reports.

Comment: The example in original question shows properly in Chrome 67 but I am having a similar problem, however this solution helped me to solve my problem too

Answer (score 2):

I posted the same issue to the Chrome feedback channels.  My workaround for now was to simply remove my thead elements for a standard table row within the tbody.  It's certainly not as semantically pure, but you can pretty simply restyle them with a touch of css.

Table:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr class="thead">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Scss:

```
tr.thead {
  td {
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
  }    
}
```

Comment: Certainly a cleaner solution than adding a second 'thead' element.  My preferred solution would keep 'thead' elements.  If no such solution is forthcoming, I will use this one.  Could you provide the link to your post on Chrome feedback?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the double header on the second page in chrome when printing

Adding the following CSS made it appear properly (once)

```
thead {
    display:table-header-group;
    break-inside: auto;
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50987624/175071

Answer (score 0):

This fix worked for me

```css
thead {
  display: table-row-group;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem:

```
tr {page-break-inside:avoid;break-inside:avoid}
```

It happens when the line is cut near from the border.